# What basis does my book have for taking $\ln(0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, logarithms

**Question:**

Determine: $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x}{1+x}dx$

**My book's attempt:**

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1-x}{1+x}dx$$

$$...$$

$$=\left[2\ln|x+1|-x \right]_{-1}^{1}$$

$$=2\ln(2)-1-2\ln(0)-1$$

$$=2\ln(2)-2$$

---

If I plug the problem in the [integral-calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=%281-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29&lbound=-1&ubound=1), it says

$$\color{red}{\text{The integral is divergent.}}$$

---

Why did my book take $\ln(0)=0$?

Comment: Which book is that?

Comment: Your book is wrong, the integral is divergent.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It's a relatively unknown Bangladeshi book.

Comment: @tryingtobeastoic This is a book you have already made multiple posts about before. It sounds as though you should stop relying on it as a source for your education.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $ a\in(-1,1]$.

$$F(a)=\int_a^1\frac{1-x}{1+x}dx$$
$$=\int_a^1(\frac{2}{1+x}-1)dx$$
$$=\Bigl[ 2\ln(1+x)-x\Bigr]_a^1$$

$$=2\ln(2)-1-2\ln(1+a)+a$$

$$\lim_{a\to-1^+}F(a)=+\infty$$
the integral is divergent.